# How to group orders by date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, group-by

now I get items in the table in this order:
11-8-2022
12-8-2022
13-8-2022

but I need to group these items in reverse order, so that the latest date will be on top
13-8-2022
12-8-2022
11-8-2022

Сan you advise me how to do this?

```
const formattedTable = async (
  orders: Order[],
) => {
  const rows = tableOrders
    .map(
      (orders: Order) =>
        `<tr>
         <td>${DateTime.fromJSDate(orders.deliveryDate).toFormat(
           "dd-MM-yyyy",
         <td>${orders.code}</td>

         )}</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data provider (e.g. backend API) guarantees that table orders are delivered in ascending dates' order, then in your code you can simply use `.reverse()` array method as follows:

```js
const formattedTable = async (
  orders: Order[],
) => {
  const rows = tableOrders
    .map(/* ...your map callback function */).reverse()
}
```

Comment: what if they're in random order?

Comment: then its not gonna work.. because reverse() is applied after mapping.

Comment: If they're not sorted in either way, then you need to manually sort it yourself before applying `map`, for example. As `DateTime` is mentioned in topics' code sample, I assume that some kind of `luxon` is used for date-related stuff handling. This lib also has comparison mechanisms, description of which you can find in the [docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=comparing-datetimes)